# Scikit-learn Custom Scoring Function 1

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

[The last line is giving me error.I am trying to solve the Titanic dataset problem of kraggle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRfey.png)

Comment: It's better if you put up your code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in above line. You forgot to close the brackets there.

Change this:

```
print(clf.predict(x_test[1:10])
```

to

```
print(clf.predict(x_test[1:10]))
```

And even after that you will get error in the line:

```
clf.f1_score(...)
```

The above line is wrong, it should be:

```
f1_score(y_test, clf.predict(x_test))
```